# Neo4j- Cypher Email validation through Regular Expression

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

How can I do filtering of junk emails using the regular expressions in Neo4j. I have very minimal knowledge on regex. The regex for email validations found in google are not working in cypher.

Please provide some example for email validation in cypher through regex.

Here is what I tried using apoc procedures in Neo4j.

**Query:**

```
MATCH (n:Person) where exists(n.person_email)
WITH n 
CALL apoc.text.regexGroups(n.person_email,'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$') YIELD value
RETURN n.person_email, value order by n.person_email LIMIT 1000
```

**Error:**

```
Invalid input '-': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', '_', '%', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 3, column 58 (offset: 111))
"CALL apoc.text.regexGroups(n.person_email,'^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$') YIELD value"
```

Note: regex is copied from google search

Comment: What kind of a regular expression did you try? How exactly?
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Again, you can easily write a user-defined function on Java.

Comment: @stdob-- Added the research I did. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, your regex is parsed in **APOC** as a java string. And because the character `\` is the **escape character in Java**, you need to double it if you really want the `\` character.

So your query becomes this one :

```
WITH "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$" AS regex
MATCH (n:Person) where exists(n.person_email)
RETURN n.person_email, apoc.text.regexGroups(n.person_email,regex) AS value 
ORDER BY n.person_email LIMIT 1000
```

Moreover, I have done some modifications on the query :

- Adding the regex as a string parameter
- `apoc.text.regexGroup` can be used as a function now

### Edit

If you just want to check the validity of a field using a regex, you can do it in plain cypher, the regex operator exists :

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WHERE  n.person_email =~ "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"
RETURN n
```

Comment: Unfortunately, regexGroups procedure is not available in 3.0.7.